# sql query(output results that are not the same between 2 tables)

Tags: sql

I have 2 table `TableA` and `TableB` with attributes of `id, character`

```
TableA
╔════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ character ║
╠════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║     A     ║
║  2 ║     B     ║
║  3 ║     C     ║
╚════╩═══════════╝

TableB
╔════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ character ║
╠════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║     A     ║
║  2 ║     B     ║
║  3 ║     D     ║
╚════╩═══════════╝
```

I want to count how many characters in the character column does not match between the `TableA` and `TableB`.

I am not sure if this is correct:

```
SELECT COUNT(character) 
FROM TableA tba 
JOIN TableB tbb 
   ON tba.id = tbb.id 
WHERE tba.character NOT LIKE tbb.character 
GROUP BY character
```

Comment: Which rdbms you use? Difference by id? Or difference in whole table?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the group by statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)   
FROM TableA tba 
INNER JOIN TableB tbb 
   ON tba.id = tbb.id 
WHERE tba.character <> tbb.character
```